# How to get the current usercontrol inside a ContentControl in MainWindow? (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I wanna know if it is posible the get the current usercontrol inside a contentcontrol of a mainview. Here's my xaml MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="MatchGameModified.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MatchGameModified"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MatchGameModified.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MatchGameModified.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="450"
    ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<!-- ViewModel revolver -->
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:StartGameViewModel}">
        <views:StartGameView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:GameViewModel}">
        <views:GameView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- Bind DataContext via XAML-->
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding PlayerName}" FontSize="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MainContent">
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I know it is posible to get the mainwindow instance from a usercontrol, but I want to get a usercontrol element.

Comment: Your question is unclear. _Where_ do you _want to get_ the `UserControl`, in XAML, where in XAML or code-behind? What dou you need the `UserControl` for, what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I wanna get an instance of a usercontrol to iterate all textblock elements and assign a value to them.

Answer (score 2):

you can add event handler to `Loaded` event of each view

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:StartGameViewModel}">
    <views:StartGameView Loaded="ViewLoaded"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:GameViewModel}">
    <views:GameView Loaded="ViewLoaded"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

and get UserControl from `sender` argument:

```
private void ViewLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var view = sender as UserControl;
}
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea. Thank you I'll try it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken your solution implies using a code-behind approach, do u know how to do it with a mvvm approach?

Comment: @GustavoGavancho, in mvvm you don't access ui elements from view model. if you need to do something view-related with them, code-behind is fine

Comment: I'll use code-behind, you're right. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @GustavoGavancho, good luck. FYI, helpful answers can be accepted via checkbox on the left side